# installation.log does not get copied to installation directory

Tags: install4j

I use install4J 5.0.9 windows-only as my product's installer. According to the manual, the installation log file should be copied upon installation completion to the installation directory.

However this doesn't happen in my installation. I have an "Install Files" action, executed as part of the "Installation Location" screen.

During the installation I can find the log under %TEMP%\I4J_log*, but it's deleted at the end of the installation (as expected).

Is there another requirement for the log to be copied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log file is moved when the installer exits and not after the "Install files" action. This is only done if the directory `${installer:sys.installationDir}/.install4j` exists. If the installer process is killed of if you call System.exit() from a script directly, this is not done either.